# How to setup email address on my domain in IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5

I have Windows Server 2008 with IIS 7.5 , I setup my domain on server.
I install SMTP on sever. Now I want to create my custom email on my domain such as:

```
owner@domain.com
```

What is the steps?

Thanks for any helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to receive and store email on your Windows 2008 server then out-of-the box you can't.

Windows and IIS doesn't come with a built-in POP3 server.